# Remove file inside docker image using spotify/docker-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, docker

My requirement was to dockerize `Spring MVC` application. `Spotify docker` maven plugin was used to create docker image of my `Spring MVC` application. I pulled `Tomcat` images and did some configurations on the `Tomcat` image. Now I want to delete `logging.properties` file in `Tomcat` image.

I read their documentation and found nothing related to this. I know how to copy files to image but I couldn't find a way to remove file.

This is how I copy files:

```
 <resource>
   <targetPath>/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/files</targetPath>
   <directory>${project.basedir}/configuration</directory>
   <include>configuration.properties</include>
 </resource>
```

Does anyone know how to remove existing file ?

Comment: Have you created your own `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I am using this one . https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete a file from tomcat image.

 The `docker exec` command is probably what you are looking for; this will let you run arbitrary commands inside an existing container.

```
$ docker ps
<mycontainerId>    xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxx   7 days ago          Up 7 days
```

then

```
docker exec -it <mycontainerId> bash
```

Comment: But i want to delete that file before container is started. So it need to be done when creating the docker image. Basically what i want to do is that  implement this docker file command using maven plugin.  'RUN rm /usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties' .